# Primefaces - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement something in JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 4.0 but I having some issues. A little time ago my `<p:editor>` was working beatifully, but now this stop working and I don't know what's the reason.

I didn't change almost anything in my code and the problem appears to be in Primefaces4.0 jar. Following is the code I use to render my `<p:editor>`:

```
<p:editor id="editor" value="#{postagemMBean.conteudo}" styleClass="n-post" />
```

The variable `postagemMBean.conteudo` comes from my DB and everything is okay with that. Now my editor doesn't render, and the only error I got is in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL editor.js.jsf:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=4.0:1
```

When I click in the error, I can see the following:

```
ï»¿(function(D){D.cleditor={defaultOptions:{width:"auto",h...
```

I tried to search `ï»¿` and this appears to be a encoding error, but this was inside the Primefaces4.0 jar, so I think this file is corrupted. I already download this file again and override this file with the new one, but this still don't work.

Something can be corrupting my file everytime? What can be the problem? How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens to me too, so it's not your file, is the primefaces file. I corrected by removing the first character (uggly one) and it worked fine. I deployed to my local nexus so the rest of the team would get the correct one. Hope they fix this quickly.

Comment: This is an old question for and old project, but at the time we did what you told us today, as this worked. To help people that have same issues, I will give you the best answer, thanks for answer and sorry for the community, I solved the problem and don't posted the answer.